# Create a JS server that archives data from a week ago

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, time

I need to create a function that can display a metric pulled at different hours of the day from an outside source one week ago.  The way I have my server currently set up is using a method that pulls a metric from an outside source at the hours between 6am and 5 pm.  The function for 6 am is shown below:

```
//get metric at 6 am
var millisTill6 = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 6, 0, 0, 0) - now;
if (millisTill6 < 0) {
    millisTill6 += 86400000; // try again tomorrow
}
setTimeout(function() {
    //get metric
}, millisTill6);
```

There are 11 more methods similar to the one above for the hours from 7 am to 5 pm that I have written to keep track of the metric at all of these times.

What I am trying to do now is store and archive the data I collect over the course of each day so that I can reference the daily data from the day one week prior to the current day (ex. if today is monday, access the data recorded last monday).  My initial thought was to create another method called `millisTillMidnight` that transitioned this data into different arrays each day, but I have not been able to get that method to work.  Ideally, I need to be able to display the hourly data from the metric in my application from one week prior to the current day of the week.

EDIT:

Have been working on this problem and still have not figured out how to get this working.  I have omitted the server URL and method to get the metric to make this question more general.  Here is the code that I have been using:

```
var http    = require('http');
var request = require('request');

var server = http.createServer(onRequest);
var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 3000)

server.listen(port);

var stat_a = [9, 9]; //display array


var tmp_stat_a = [0, 0]; //Holds the metric data for the day

var m_stat_a = [1, 1]; //monday archive
var t_stat_a = [2, 2]; //tuesday archive
var w_stat_a = [3, 3]; //wednesday archive
var th_stat_a = [4, 4]; //thursday archive
var f_stat_a = [5, 5]; //friday archive
var sa_stat_a = [6, 6]; //saturday archive
var s_stat_a = [7, 7]; //sunday archive


//----------------------------------------------------
function onRequest(req, res){

    var Url = //URL

    request(Url, function (error, response, body) {

        var data   = error;
        var status = 404;

        if(!error){

            var now = new Date();


            var millisTill6 = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 6, 0, 0, 0) - now;//6 AM
            if (millisTill6 < 0) {
                millisTill6 += 86400000;
            }
            setTimeout(function(){
                            tmp_stat_a[0] = //get metric

                        }, millisTill6);

            var millisTill7 = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 7, 0, 0, 0) - now; //7 AM
            if (millisTill7 < 0) {
                millisTill7 += 86400000;
            }
            setTimeout(function(){
                            tmp_stat_a[1] = //get metric

                        }, millisTill7);


            var millisTillMidnight = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 23, 58, 0, 0) - now; //archive temp array and display data for next day at midnight
            if (millisTillMidnight < 0) {
                millisTillMidnight += 86400000;
            }
            setTimeout(function(){

                            var d = new Date();
                            var n = d.getDay();

                            if(n == 0) //SUNDAY
                            {
                                for(i=0; i<2; i++)
                                {
                                    s_stat_a[i] = tmp_stat_a[i]; //archive temp array

                                    stat_a[i] = m_stat_a[i]; //set display array to last weeks archive for the next day
                                }
                                console.log("0");
                            }


                            else if(n == 1) //MONDAY
                            {
                                for(i=0; i<2; i++)
                                {
                                    m_stat_a[i] = tmp_stat_a[i];

                                    stat_a[i] = t_stat_a[i];
                                }
                                console.log("1");
                            }
                            else if(n == 2) //TUESDAY
                            {
                                for(i=0; i<2; i++)
                                {
                                    t_stat_a[i] = tmp_stat_a[i];

                                    stat_a[i] = w_stat_a[i];
                                }
                                console.log("2");
                            }
                            else if(n == 3)  //WEDNESDAY
                            {
                                for(i=0; i<2; i++)
                                {
                                    w_stat_a[i] = tmp_stat_a[i];

                                    stat_a[i] = th_stat_a[i];
                                }
                                console.log("3");
                            }
                            else if(n == 4) //THURSDAY
                            {
                                for(i=0; i<2; i++)
                                {
                                    th_stat_a[i] = tmp_stat_a[i];

                                    stat_a[i] = f_stat_a[i];
                                }
                                console.log("4");
                            }
                            else if(n == 5) //FRIDAY
                            {
                                for(i=0; i<2; i++)
                                {
                                    f_stat_a[i] = tmp_stat_a[i];

                                    stat_a[i] = sa_stat_a[i];
                                }
                                console.log("5");
                            }
                            else if(n == 6) //SATURDAY
                            {
                                for(i=0; i<2; i++)
                                {
                                    sa_stat_a[i] = tmp_stat_a[i];

                                    stat_a[i] = s_stat_a[i];
                                }
                                console.log("6");
                            }


                        }, millisTillMidnight);

            status = 200;
            data = {
                aa: stat_a[0],
                ab: stat_a[1]

            };
        }

        res.writeHead(status, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*" });
        res.write(JSON.stringify(data));
        res.end();
    });
}
```

Comment: You need a database on a server to do this unless you are hoping that the client keeps the page open for a week to collect all the data in memory.

Comment: The JS program above will be hosted on a server that a different JS file pulls from so the prorgam above will always be running.

Comment: So create a database and store the metrics you pull into the database. I am guessing you are using node.js...node.js works with all major datastores so pick one, create the tables you need and store the data there.

Comment: Basically you need a database like MySQL to store all the metrics you pull. Or if thats too much work, write all the data to text files and label the text files appropriately.

Comment: This OP is a true OG

Comment: @ytpillai  What are you talking about

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I understand the questions but I believe you are asking for how to find out milliseconds till midnight.. If that is the case use the following... Pardon in advance if I misunderstood.

```
var now = new Date();
var midnightDate = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 24, 0, 0, 0);
console.log(midnightDate); //This is midnight... ie. if run on July 6th, this is - Thu Jul 07 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
var millsTillMidnight = midnightDate - new Date();
console.log(millsTillMidnight);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for trying.  I am trying to write a program that can be used as a back end for a chart that displays data from a wek ago.  I have a program that can get a metric for 12 different hours of the day.  I need a way to be able to collect the metric for all 12 hours of the day, store it for a week, and then be able to access that week old data from the current day.  The solution would include a way to store 7 days worth of data for 12 different data points that were updated every night at midnight by putting the current day's data into archive.

Comment: So you are looking for a system to store the data and then retrieve it?